# globals from multiple modules not visible to exec code?

Tags: python, module, exec

My app executes bits of python logic stored in a configuration file via exec, as in:

```
"foo() + 2"
```

This logic commonly references symbols that I store in a module named "standard". For example, in the above, you can see the logic accesses the method foo(), and foo is defined inside standard.py:

```
def foo():...
```

To provide the logic with access to the symbols in standard, I'm extracting out the methods from standard into a dictionary, like so:

```
import standard
my_globals = standard.__dict__
```

Then I'm adding in a few other relevant symbols to my_globals (which I don't show here) and providing them to the logic, when I execute it:

```
exec("foo() + 2", my_globals)
```

This is working. When I look at globals() from inside foo(), I can see other methods I defined in the module standard.py as well as the other relevant symbols I mentioned above and foo() can access all of those things.

The problem comes in when I want to make another module of functions available to the logic as well. Let's say I have a module named custom.py that has some other symbols I want the logic to access. I'm trying to make those symbols available as well by doing this:

```
import custom
my_globals.update(custom.__dict__)
```

Let's say my logic now is "bar() + 1", where "bar" is defined inside of custom.py. bar() also wants to access some of those relevant other symbols I added into my_globals.

The problem I'm running in to is that code inside of custom is only seeing the symbols defined inside custom.py, and not everything else stored in my_globals. IE, bar() can't see foo(), nor the other stuff I tucked away into my_globals.

Yet foo() can. It's code can see any other methods I defined in standard, as well as symbols defined in custom, as well as the "extra" symbols I plugged into my_globals.

Why is this happening? My expectation is that the logic being executed is run in the context of the contents of my_globals, so it seems like both foo() and bar() should be able to access any and all symbols in my_globals.

I suspect this has to do with how I'm creating my_globals. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to make sure I'm getting this correct ... You're trying to access names from `custom` from _inside_ a function that is defined in `standard`, but you don't want to import `custom` in `standard`?

Comment: Remember, my_globals is essentially an alias for standard.__dict__, but not for custom.__dict__.  You have not done anything to change the latter.  But I would suggest not messing with standard.__dict__ at all.  You could keep your globals in a class (or even just a dict) defined in standard.py, then `from standard import globals` in your other modules as needed.

Comment: My 1st goal is that the bit of exec'd code can call any of the methods defined in either standard or custom, which is why I was trying to copy both of their __dicts__ into my_globals, and then pass my_globals to exec. But that isn't exactly working. As far as methods in custom accessing standard, I understand custom will have to import standard.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some insight:

> "To provide the logic with access to the symbols in standard, I'm extracting out the methods from standard into a dictionary, like so:"

```
import standard
my_globals = standard.__dict__
```

**Not exactly**.  You're just creating a local variable, `my_globals` that now points to `standard.__dict__`.  Whenever you update `my_globals`, you're *really* just updating `standard.__dict__`.

When you add your other symbols to `my_globals`, again, you're just adding them to `standard.__dict__`.

Calling:

```
exec("foo() + 2", my_globals)
```

works great when `foo` is defined in standard.py, because you've added all the other methods to this module - you now have access to them all.

When you do:

```
import custom
my_globals.update(custom.__dict__)
```

You've added your "symbols" from custom.py to the standard module.  All the functions in standard can access functions from custom.py after this point

Unfortunately, custom.py itself, doesn't have direct access to the methods in standard.py (unless you import them).  From within custom.py, you can see that everything you've created is in standard now:

(from within custom.py):

```
import sys

def custom_foo():
    print(dir(sys.modules['standard']))  # shows that you've put everything in here
    sys.modules['standard'].foo()  # calls foo from standard.py (assuming you've imported standard in your main pgm)
```

Above is really ugly though - you could just add a:

```
from standard import *
```

at the top of custom.py, and you would have access to everything you've added to its `__dict__` instead.

I doubt you *really* want to do what you're attempting with the whole `exec` thing, but I'm not really sure what your use case is.

**EDIT:**

If you really want all the symbols you've attached to `my_globals` available to the methods of custom.py, you could call:

```
custom.__dict__.update(my_globals)
```

After this point, functions in custom.py would have access to everything you've added to the standard.**dict** (aka my_globals).  (You've also overrode any functions defined in custom.py with functions of the same name in `my_globals`)

Please note, doing things this way is pretty atypical (read: somewhat ill advised).

Comment: part of my problem might be that I don't understand modules+exec as well as I thought. I thought I could basically put a reference to any method from any module into a dict, thus sort of divorcing the method from its module,  and pass that dict to exec, and those methods in that dict would basically provide the "global scope" for the exec'd code and the exec'd code code call any of those methods.

Comment: fyi the use case is that my app (a website) services multiple clients. For each client we have these snippets of python code that tell us how to compute something. Usually these snippets call methods in "standard" which are common across all clients. But sometimes we need a separate module to hold custom code that is client specific and we don't want to clutter up standard with it.  So my hope was that I could rig things up so these snippets could access functions in standard, and custom, when a custom module is present.

Comment: So I thought I could essentially copy references to all methods in both standard and custom, into one dictionary, that I pass to exec and the snippets could see all these methods without realizing or caring that are part of one module or the other.

Comment: in our example, and your  answer above, it seems odd that methods in standard can see all the methods I've plugged into my_globals yet the methods in custom only see it's own. It's almost like their methods are "ignoring" the dict I'm passing in to exec and are resolving symbol references against their own module dict.

Comment: It is a little confusing, but once again, the methods in standard can see all of the methods you've plugged into my_globals **because you've really just plugged them into standard itself**.  You've monkey-patched your standard module, so that it actually contains all the symbols that you plugged in. It is more or less the equivalent of editing standard.py itself and either defining them there, or importing them.  Since you've monkey-patched the standard module with everything you want, you could just have a "from standard import *" at the top of every custom module.